# Is it possible to get alarm data for the map widget in Thingsboard?

Tags: google-maps, alarm, thingsboard

[image]I am trying to change my marker based on an alarm I've created in Thingsboard.  Currently the marker is displaying data from my "datasource" entity.  However there is no way (that I have seen) that you can add an "Alarm source" similar to the alarm widget.

The data available is "f(data, images, dsData, dsIndex)" which I assume is only the data telemetry.

Basically I need to change the marker if an alarm is going off.  My alarm trigger only goes off momentarily so I can't use my data telemetry directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a new "Save attribute" on the alarm rule chain, after the alarm is created. Combined with a "Change originator" you can save the attribute to a specific device. 
Then on the map widget you can add the new attribute to the datasource and act as per that attribute.
It is a bit non-conventional approach, but it should probably work for you.

You should have a "Change Originator"--> "Script" --> "Save Attribute"
On the script item you should insert the new attribute to the data and update the msgType to "POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST". I'm not sure if you need to update the message or metadata, but I guess you can try and see.

Script code:

```
msg = {};
msg.alarm = true;
metadata = {};
metadata.alarm = true;
msgType = "POST_ATTRIBUTES_REQUEST";
return {msg: msg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```

Comment: I did what you mentioned however I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported msg type: ALARM" on the Save Attributes node.  Does the Originator node come before or after the Save Attributes node?

Comment: Need to update the msgType using a script before sending the data to the save attribute node. Updated my answer.